# Adding a Custom Webpart to a Site Template in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I tried to add a custom created webpart to a customized team site which I then saved as a template. The webpart in question worked fine with the original site. However, when I created a new site based on this template(within the same server that the webpart in question was deployed to) the area which was supposed to contain the webpart was blank. Is there anything I'm missing or is it not possible to deploy a custom webpart into a custom site template?

Comment: Did you had the assembly deployed to target server corresponding to custom web part ?

Comment: Yes, I deployed through Visual Studio before adding the template to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing here because I haven't tried it but when you add a webpart to the page you are essentially customizing that page for that specific site.  The webpart location is stored in the content database just for that individual page.

When you save a site as a template you are just saving the structure so when you provision a new site the customized page isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lee, I actually sorted it out a little while back. Turns out the webpart was throwing an exception. I did not see this until I examined the logs correctly. I made a change to the webpart code and redeployed it, and now it seems to work.
Thanks for helping!!